# Meteor: Search user by name and order results by "Nearby" location

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

I have user collection and i am searching user by name using:

```
Meteor.users.find({ $and:[{"profile.type": "doctor"},
{"profile.name": {$regex: new RegExp((Session.get("doctorSearchQuery")))}}]});
```

and its returning me exact user.

In my User collection i have `addressOne` field which is getting user location in longitude and latitude points using [autoform-map](https://atmospherejs.com/yogiben/autoform-map) package. Here is that field: 
`addressOne: {
    type: [Number],
    decimal: true,
    autoform: {
      label: false,
      type: 'map',
      afFieldInput: {
        geolocation: true,
        searchBox: true,
        autolocate: true
      }
    }
  },`

Now my question is how i can sort above search result by nearby location. I have tried using [$near](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/near/) and [$geoNear](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/#pipe._S_geoNear), as i am not much familiar with mongodb syntax so could not get desire results.